# Conjecture on connected hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, graph-colorings, hypergraph

A [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ with $V$ non-empty is said to be *connected* if for all $S\subseteq V$ with $\emptyset \neq S \neq V$ there is $e\in E$ such that $e$ intersects both $S$ and $V\setminus S$.

Given a non-empty subset $T$ of $V$, we let $(T, E|_T)$ with $E|_T := \{e\cap T: e\in E\}$ be the *subhypergraph* induced by $T$. By slight abuse of nomenclature we call $T$  connected if its induced hypergraph $(T, E|_T)$ is connected.

If $\kappa\neq \emptyset$ we say that $H=(V,E)$ is *colorable with $\kappa$ colors* if there is a map $c:V\to \kappa$ such that the restriction $c|_e: e\to \kappa$ is non-constant whenever $e$ has more than $1$ element.

**Conjecture.** If $H=(V,E)$ is a hypergraph with $V$ non-empty, and $\kappa$ is a non-empty cardinal (finite or infinite) such that $H$ is **not** colorable with $\kappa$ colors, then there is a collection ${\cal S}$ consisting of $\kappa$ non-empty, connected, and pairwise disjoint subsets of $V$ such that

> whenever $S_0\neq S_1\in{\cal S}$ then there is an edge $e\in E$ intersecting both $S_0$ and $S_1$.

Is this conjecture true?

Comment: By replacing hyperedges with cliques, this conjecture would follow from the special case of graphs, so there is no need to consider hypergraphs.

Comment: for the graph case, is it possible that not being $\kappa$-colorable could be weakened to not being $(\kappa-1)$-degenerate?

Comment: @WillSawin If you replace hyperedges by cliques, you change the chromatic number. For instance if ${\cal E}$ is a countable collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$, then $(\omega, {\cal E})$ is colorable with $2$ colors, but if you replace every hyperedge with a clique, then the resulting graph has chromatic number $\aleph_0$. So this conjecture is much weaker.

Comment: Your conjecture cannot be weaker because it includes graphs as a special case.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some subtle difference, it seems like you already asked this question three months ago...
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413206/a-form-of-hadwigers-conjecture-for-hypergraphs

Comment: Also in the case of finite graphs, this would give by far the best known approximate version of Hadwiger's conjecture (only off by 1).